# The connectionTimeout seems not work after setting the proxy in jodd-http(6.0.2)

Tags: http, proxy, jodd, connect-timeout

Here is my code

```
import jodd.http.*;
import jodd.http.net.*;
public class JoddQuestion {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SocketHttpConnectionProvider connectionProvider = new SocketHttpConnectionProvider();
        ProxyInfo proxyInfo = ProxyInfo.httpProxy("xxxx", xx, "xxxx", "xxxx");
        connectionProvider.useProxy(proxyInfo);

        String url = "http://www.google.com";
        HttpResponse response = HttpRequest.get(url).open(connectionProvider).connectionTimeout(1000).timeout(1000).followRedirects(true).send();
        System.out.print(response.bodyText());
    }
}
```

Google website is blocked by firewall in China. Without setting the proxy, run the program, connectionTimeout works.

```
HttpResponse response = HttpRequest.get(url).connectionTimeout(1000).timeout(1000).followRedirects(true).send();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/og8r4.png)

However, after setting the proxy, connectionTimeout does not work and program just keeps trying.

```
HttpResponse response = HttpRequest.get(url).open(connectionProvider).connectionTimeout(1000).timeout(1000).followRedirects(true).send();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htrp1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `open()` method opens the connection (and therefore applies the **previously** set timeouts. Anything set *after* the call to `open()` will not be applied.

You probably want to use the method: `withConnectionProvider()` instead of `open()` - it will just set the provider and not open the connection. Then the timeout will be applied when the connection is actually opened.

Read more here: https://http.jodd.org/connection#sockethttpconnectionprovider

Or just use `open()` as the last method before sending. But I would strongly avoid using `open` without a good reason: just use `send()` as it will open the connection.

EDIT: please upgrade to Jodd HTTP **v6.0.6** to prevent some non-related issues, mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But when I use withConnectionProvider,every wibesite can not reach. Here is the code:`HttpResponse response = HttpRequest.get(url).withConnectionProvider(connectionProvider).connectionTimeout(1000).timeout(1000).followRedirects(true).send();`